# Google chrome - chrome.serial connection failed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, serial-communication

I am trying to connect to USB serial which is working manually as below:

```
$ ls /dev/cu.*
/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port /dev/cu.usbserial
$ screen /dev/cu.usbserial 9600
```

But when Google chrome apps trying to connect its failing.

[image]

apps, background.js:

```
var DEVICE_PATH = '/dev/cu.usbserial';
var serial = chrome.serial;

function log(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}

var ab2str = function(buf) {
  var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
  var encodedString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bufView);
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(encodedString));
};

var str2ab = function(str) {
  var encodedString = unescape((str));
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(1);
  bytes[0] = parseInt(encodedString);
  return bytes.buffer;
};

// Object
var SerialConnection = function() {
  this.connectionId = -1;
  this.lineBuffer = "";
  this.receiveTimeout =50;
  this.boundOnReceive = this.onReceive.bind(this);
  this.boundOnReceiveError = this.onReceiveError.bind(this);
  this.onConnect = new chrome.Event();
  this.onReadLine = new chrome.Event();
  this.onError = new chrome.Event();
};

SerialConnection.prototype.onConnectComplete = function(connectionInfo) {
  if (!connectionInfo) {
    log("Connection failed.");
    return;
  }
  this.connectionId = connectionInfo.connectionId;
  chrome.serial.onReceive.addListener(this.boundOnReceive);
  chrome.serial.onReceiveError.addListener(this.boundOnReceiveError);
  this.onConnect.dispatch();
};

SerialConnection.prototype.onReceive = function(receiveInfo) {
  if (receiveInfo.connectionId !== this.connectionId) {
    return;
  }

  this.lineBuffer += ab2str(receiveInfo.data);

  var index;
  while ((index = this.lineBuffer.indexOf('$')) >= 0) {
    var line = this.lineBuffer.substr(0, index + 1);
    this.onReadLine.dispatch(line);
    this.lineBuffer = this.lineBuffer.substr(index + 1);
  }
};

SerialConnection.prototype.onReceiveError = function(errorInfo) {
  log('Error');
  if (errorInfo.connectionId === this.connectionId) {
    log('Error');
    this.onError.dispatch(errorInfo.error);
    log('Error');
  }
  log('Error');
};

SerialConnection.prototype.connect = function(path) {
  serial.connect(path, {bitrate: 9600}, this.onConnectComplete.bind(this));
};

SerialConnection.prototype.send = function(msg) {
  if (this.connectionId < 0) {
    throw 'Invalid connection';
  }
  serial.send(this.connectionId, str2ab(msg), function() {});
};

SerialConnection.prototype.disconnect = function() {
  if (this.connectionId < 0) {
    throw 'Invalid connection';
  }
  serial.disconnect(this.connectionId, function() {});
};

// -- Connect
var connection = new SerialConnection();
connection.onConnect.addListener(function() {
  log('connected to: ' + DEVICE_PATH);
});

connection.onReadLine.addListener(function(line) {
  log('read line: ' + line);
});

connection.onError.addListener(function() {
  log('Error: ');
});
connection.connect(DEVICE_PATH);
```

Comment: There is an API for interacting with USB. See [chrome.usb](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb). "Use the chrome.usb API to interact with connected USB devices. This API provides access to USB operations from within the context of an app. Using this API, apps can function as drivers for hardware devices. Errors generated by this API are reported by setting runtime.lastError and executing the function's regular callback. The callback's regular parameters will be undefined in this case. "

Comment: chrome.usb is not for serial reader. can you please check in details? question was to make chrome.serial work not the chrome.usb.

Comment: is this a BUG? chrome.serial not working always connection fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USB access on OSX, found that Chrome does not gain access to the USB device until the native client application (using hidapi) is running and recognize the device.

Use Windows OS with same code, then it works.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=584599 - please star this issue in issue tracker and report that the same problem you also have. in OSX Google Chrome serial does not work because Google Chrome not using native client application (hidapi). But same thing works on Windows operating system. You have to open the eyes of Google Chrome community that,  it is failing with you too, if you have many people reporting same problem on that issue tracker link. Then Google Chrome community will fix it. So please follow up in the reported issue tracker url.