# chrome.serial.getDevices() hangs on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, serial-port

I have a packaged Chrome app that is trying to read from a serial port. However, everytime I call `chrome.serial.getDevices()`, it doesn't return (nor does my function get called).

My code is as simple as reacting to a click on my browser action button:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var onGetDevices = function(ports) {
        alert("Devices");
        for (var i=0; i<ports.length; i++) {
            alert(ports[i].path);
        }   
    }
    alert("before");
    chrome.serial.getDevices(onGetDevices);
    alert("after");
});
```

The `before` message gets displayed, but the `after` one doesn't. I've similarly tried invoking `connect()` directly, but it too doesn't return.

```
chrome.serial.connect("/dev/tty.usbserial-AI02KQN0", {bitrate: 9600}, onConnect);
```

I've read a number of [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200639/google-chrome-chrome-serial-connection-failed) that suggest that Chrome on a Mac isn't able to read from the serial port properly, but I'm not sure if I'm suffering from this problem, or something else.

Any ideas? Do I need to move to a Windows machine? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

man... I should know better. Turns out that I was still shipping it as an extension, not as an app. Once I make it an app, the list of devices are successfully returned.